# Circle shape drawable with fill color

Tags: android

I am using the following code to create a circle with fill color

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#E00000" />
   <padding
       android:left="2dp"
       android:right="2dp"
       android:top="2dp"
       android:bottom="2dp" />

 </shape>
```

The problem is that I get circle with NO fill color? If I change it with oval, I get the oval with fill color.

How  can I get circle with fill color?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this `shape` as a background, then yes it will be drawn. In `shape`, there is no `circle`. There is just `oval`. If you want to draw a `circle` out of it, you need set the `height` and the `width` as the same. That's the only way. You can either do it in the `shape` drawable itself, or in the view that you are using this.

Put this in `shape` drawable, to set the size:

```
<size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
```

If you don't mention the `size` for the `shape` drawable, and if you use this drawable as `src` in an `ImageView` with `wrap_content`, there won't be any circle drawn.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and suggestion. When I use ring, why wouldnt it fill it with red color although I used the fill attribute?

Comment: Did you set `thickness` for ring?

Comment: No I didn't , but that's thickness of stroke

Comment: No it is not the stroke. You need to use `innerRadius` and `thickness` to draw the ring.. `thickness` is the area that will be colored.

Comment: I see... Thank you for the comment :)